# Values under xAxis doesn't display in LineChart MPAdroidChart

Tags: android, charts

I have created such chart, but problem is that values under xAxis doesn't displays fully, so there should be "2017-08-10", instead I see "20", If I zoom that chart, I can see all data under the xAxis. How to see all values?
I have also tried to change RotationAngle to 25 and 90, but still no results.

```
                    XAxis xAxis = chart.getXAxis();
                    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyXAxisValueFormatter(datesArray));
                    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(45);
                    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
                    chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
```

[image]

I have also removed  `xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(45);`But, in that case dates overlap each other.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set bottom padding to chart using **setExtraOffsets** like.

```
setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)
```

Comment: I have already tried that, in that case, dates just overlap each other

Comment: I would like to show all date, maybe if I will show just 8 Aug, it would overlap so badly.

Comment: Then set the font size of label like..   xAxis.setTextSize(24f);

Comment: I have also tried it, it just makes this that dates bigger.

Comment: Try to use minimum size 10f or 12f

Comment: **setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom)** use this to set bottom padding and set your label rotate to 45

Comment: Just have done that, I have one more question about Chart. maybe you know the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650691/change-color-of-the-supportive-lines-in-linechart-mpandroidchart

Comment: And edit your answer to setExtraOffsets(float left, float top, float right, float bottom) instead of "remove this line xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(45);"

Comment: I will give solution to your next que after some time