# Change color of the supportive lines in LineChart MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts

I have a LineChart, and when I touch at some point, there appear two lines. How to change the color of that lines? or how to disable them? By supportive lines I mean that orange lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **LineDataSet.setHighLightColor(//your color)** method